# Correctly handling data abort exception when branch follows load

Tags: exception, arm

I am somewhat confused with proper way to handle data abort exceptions on ARM CPU.

For example [this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0333h/DDI0333H_arm1176jzs_r0p7_trm.pdf) document says that when data abort exception state is entered LR register is set to the address of PC-8.  I assume that the 2 instructions following faulty load or store instruction got fetched into the pipeline.  But is it really safe to return to the PC-8 address. What if the instruction immediately following faulty load instruction was a branch.  Does it mean that PC register is actually set to the branch destination instruction and not the one that sequentially follows the load instruction.  In this case returning to PC-8 will return to some random place in the program  2 steps behind the branch destination )
and not to the faulty load instruction.   Am I missing something here?

Comment: Exactly what ARM-based processor are you using? If it's STM32, then this might help you with it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21329948/1382251.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an `LDR` or `STR` aborts and one of the two following instructions is a branch then the branch will not have had any effect yet and the `LR` of Abort mode will contain the address of the aborting instruction + 8.  So `LR-8` is the address to return to if you want to re-execute the aborting instruction.